# React-Router-Dom 6 - How to dynamically render a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My old method:

```
          <Route
            key={i}
            path={path}
            render={(props) => {
              if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
                <Redirect
                to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
                />
              }
              return (
                <AuthLayout>
                  <Component {...props} />
                </AuthLayout>
              );
            }}
          />
```

Replacing `render` with the new `element` gives me:

> Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render

Apparently the new API simply expects:

```
          <Route
            key={i}
            path={path}
            element={
                <Component />
            }
          />
```

What I'm really trying to accomplish is to dynamically render the component as such:

```
        {authProtectedRoutes.map(({ path, Component }, i) => {
          <Route
            key={i}
            path={path}
            element={
              // If no auth token, redirect to login
              if (!token) {
                <Navigate to="/login" />
              } else {
                <AuthLayout>
                  <Component />
                </AuthLayout>
              }
            }
          />
        })}
```

Not sure how to do this ...

EDIT:

My array of components is as such:

```
const authProtectedRoutes = [
  { path: "/dashboard", Component: Dashboard },
  { path: "/pages-starter", Component: StarterPage },
```

When I try to return `Component` in my loop I get:

> React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element={
  // If no auth token, redirect to login
  if (!token) {
    <Navigate to="/login" />
  } else {
    <AuthLayout>
      <Component />
    </AuthLayout>
  }
}
```

You can't do an `if` in the middle of jsx, but you can do a conditional operator:

```
element={!token ? (
  <Navigate to="/login" />
) : (
  <AuthLayout>
    <Component />
  </AuthLayout>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks that's one step. Can you see my Edit? I'm doing something else wrong

Comment: As the error message says, it's probably an issue with the way you're importing and exporting components. Double check that you're importing them correctly. Eg, if Dashboard is exported as a default export, then import it via `import Dashboard from 'path/to/file'`, or if it's a named export then import it via `import { Dashboard } from 'path/to/file'`. If you're not sure which component is causing the problem, try adding a console.log statement (eg, `console.log(Dashboard, StarterPage)`)

Comment: The component is def imported correctly, it's just that i'm passing it via an object property in the loop and don't know how to render it.

Answer (score 1):

Nice routing-related question. First of all, I found useful code example from react-router-dom's github: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/2cd8266765925f8e4651d7caf42ebe60ec8e163a/examples/auth/src/App.tsx#L104

Here, instead of putting some logics inside "element" or "render" authors suggest to implement additional RequireAuth component and use it in routing setup like following:

```
<Route
  path="/protected"
  element={
    <RequireAuth>
      <SomePageComponent />
    </RequireAuth>
  }
....
```

This approach would allow to incapsulate auth-related checks inside this new RequireAuth component and as a result make your application routing setup more "lightweight"

As a "brief" example, I created following piece of code you could reference to:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <AppRoutes />
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}


const RequireAuth = ({ children }) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const currentUrl = useHref();
    return !token ? (
        <Navigate to={`/login?redirect=${currentUrl}`} />
    ) : (
        children
    );
};

const authProtectedRoutes = [
    { path: '/', component: PaymentsPage },
    { path: '/user', component: UserInfoPage },
];

const AppRoutes = () => (
    <Routes>
        {authProtectedRoutes.map((r) => (
            <Route
                key={r.path}
                path={r.path}
                element={
                    <RequireAuth>
                        <AuthLayout>
                            <r.component />
                        </AuthLayout>
                    </RequireAuth>
                }
            />
        ))}
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
    </Routes>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `element` prop expects a `ReactNode` (*a.k.a. JSX*) and not javascript (*i.e. the if-statement*).

Since it seems you render your authenticated routes in bulk a more optimal solution would be to wrap them all in a single `AuthLayout` component that checks the token. Instead of rendering the `children` prop it renders an `Outlet` for nested routes to be rendered into.

Example:

```
const AuthLayout = ({ token }) => {
  // ... existing AuthLayout logic

  return token
    ? (
      <div /* awesome auth layout CSS style */>
        ...
        <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render here
      </div>
    )
    : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};
```

Don't forget to return the `Route` from the map callback.

```
<Route element={<AuthLayout token={token} />}>
  {authProtectedRoutes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
    <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component />} />
  ))}
</Route>
```